# Move specific data to another sheet in the last row of specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am going to make a checking list. In this sheet, there are many person and to do list with check box. If something done,I'll click the check box, then move the data to another sheet in the last row of specific column. My question is with my code, when data is moved, it'll be affected by other columns as picture shown below. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzy9M.png)

I hope the data can continue to be sorted. My goal is to fix this first, then I will try to write loop to make it brief. As my code experience is limited, I have google but didn't work at all.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named by_person
  // target sheet of move to named Completed
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "by_person" && r.getColumn() == 1 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();  
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2).moveTo(target); 
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, 2).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);

  } else if(s.getName() == "by_person" && r.getColumn() == 3 && r.getValue() == true) {
    var row = r.getRow();  
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 3);
    s.getRange(row, 3, 1, 2).moveTo(target);
    s.getRange(row, 3, 1, 2).deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your showing script, I thought that the reason for your current issue is due to `getLastRow()`. When `getLastRow()` is run, the value of the last row of the sheet is retrieved.
- I thought that when the event object is used, the process cost can be reduced.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
  Object.prototype.get1stEmptyRowFromTop = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
    const range = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, 2);
    const values = range.getDisplayValues();
    if (values[0][0] && values[1][0]) {
      return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getRow() + 1;
    } else if (values[0][0] && !values[1][0]) {
      return offsetRow + 1;
    }
    return offsetRow;
  };

  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.range;
  if (s.getName() == "by_person" && [1, 3].includes(r.columnStart) && r.isChecked()) {
    var targetSheet = event.source.getSheetByName("completed");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.get1stEmptyRowFromTop(r.columnStart), r.columnStart);
    var source = s.getRange(r.rowStart, r.columnStart, 1, 2);
    source.moveTo(target);
    source.deleteCells(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS);
  }
}
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I appreciate it :)

Comment: @Sarah About `It works! Thank you so much. I appreciate it :)`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Done. Thank you for the reminder~

Comment: @Sarah Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.